# Prove $(\forall x (P(x) \to \exists y Q(x, y))) \to (\exists x P(x) \to \exists y Q(x, y))$

Tags: predicate-logic

What I did was to first assume

$$ \forall x (P(x) \to \exists y Q(x, y))$$
Assume a free variable $x_0$

then doing a universal quantifier elimination

$$P(x_0) \to \exists y Q(x_0, y)$$

Now assuming $P(x_0)$

Using implication elimination

$$ \exists y Q(x_0, y)$$

This is all I managed to do because I was unable to remove the final line from the scope of $x_0$ assumption since there is no quantifier for x. How should I proceed?

Comment: What type of proof are you looking for? What rules are you allowed?

Comment: I don't believe it is a well-formed formula.

Comment: @Shaun just natural deduction ig

Comment: @Shaun why is it not a wff

Comment: The second $Q$ has no quantifiers.

Comment: @Shaun Sorry for that, fixed it now

Comment: This is still not correct. $x$ is a free variable in $\exists y\text{ }Q(x,y)$ in the second formula.

Comment: Let the domain be real numbers, $P(x)$ is "x is positive", $Q(x,y)$ is "$y^2=x$". Then the antecedent (sentence) is true (for any assignment), but the consequent is false for the assignment $x$ -> $-17$, and thus the whole formula not satisfied by that assignment.